# Why use getters to const private members instead of making them public?

Tags: c++, constants, getter, public, data-hiding

Suppose I have a simple class that defines a Circle object:

```
class Circle {
public:
    Circle(const double x): radius(x) { ; }
    const double getRadius() const { return radius; }

private:
    const double radius;

};
```

This seems like a common convention and subscribes to the OO principle of data-hiding.  My question is *why do this?*  Would it not be simpler to make `radius` a public member?  For a mutable member, this would obviously be a bad idea, since anyone could modify the circle's radius, but since it's const, I see no need to make it private.  Would it be acceptable to do something like this?:

```
class Circle {
public:
    Circle(const double x): radius(x) { ; }
    const double radius;
};
```

Comment: E.g. so that you could later change implementation to one where the radius is not stored as a member variable but is computed (e.g. you decide to store the diameter instead), without breaking any calling code.

Comment: Quite a few classes don't have `const` members (initialised only as an object is constructed) either.   Quite a few classes have operations that change data members, so an object's state can evolve over time.    Having some members (whether `const` or not) that are accessed by a member function call (e.g.  `some_circle.circumference()`) and some members that are accessed directly (e.g. `some_circle.radius`) tends to catch out programmers - little mistakes of using one when only the other is supported, and such mistakes add up in terms of lost time or productivity.

Comment: A setter can validate the parameter value to make sure it is sensical.  (So the object is in a valid state, because the invariants are met.)  For example, a circle's radius should be greater than zero.  Without a setter, some code may put any value it wants in there, even if it does not meet the class's invariant.

Comment: @Eljay The question is about a **getter** on const private property. As const it cannot be set:

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle • Skimmed too fast.  Brain segfault.